# SharePoint 2013 calculated column formula help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a formula similar to what we use in our PWA environment but this is just for SP.  I tried using my formula from PWA but it would not work.  What I am trying to do is something like this

`=IF(AND[Due Date]<NOW(), [% Complete]<100%,"Late")`

I will be adding additional IF statements to this formula as well to represent On Schedule, Complete and at Risk

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the error is from a syntax error, then you are missing a parentheses for the AND:

=IF(  AND( [Due Date]

As you did not include the error, only "it does not work", you could also mean the values are not being recalculated over time. SharePoint Calculated Columns are only recalculated when the item is created or edited, not on each view of the list. I.e. the result of the formula is static.